# UIButton subclass displays wrongly

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a button that's created via a NIB file. I've derived a class from `UIButton`, replaced the class name in the NIB file.

Now my button displays with no background. The text is there, the text font and color are right, and it reacts to taps as expected, but it's as if the background is transparent. In the NIB, it's not transparent - I did not change any of the properties other than the class name.

The subclass is trivial - it overrides nothing (for now). Please, what am I doing wrong?

The reason I need a subclass of UIButton is because I want to be able, under certain circumstances, to drag text from the button to elsewhere. If there's an alternative way to handle drag and drop in a UIKit provided view, I'm willing to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly not sure what's wrong with the subclass, but the 'Net (including SO) is full of cautionary tales about subclassing UIButton, and how you shouldn't.

So I'll go with method swizzling on the four touch processing methods. The following function replaces the provided method of a button with my implementation (taken from the MyButton class), while saving the old one in the system button class under a different selector:

```
//Does NOT look at superclasses
static bool MethodInClass(Class c, SEL sel)
{
    unsigned n,i ;
    Method *m = class_copyMethodList(c, &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(sel_isEqual(method_getName(m[i]), sel))
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static void MountMethod(Class &buc, SEL SrcSel, SEL SaveSlotSel)
{
    IMP OldImp = [buc instanceMethodForSelector:SrcSel];
    IMP NewImp = [[MyButton class] instanceMethodForSelector:SrcSel];
    if(OldImp && NewImp)
    {
        //Save the old implementation. Might conflict if the technique is used
        //independently on many classes in the same hierarchy
        Method SaveMe = class_getInstanceMethod(buc, SaveSlotSel);
        if(SaveMe == NULL)
            class_addMethod(buc, SaveSlotSel, OldImp, "v@:@@");
        else
            method_setImplementation(SaveMe, OldImp);

        //Note: the method's original implemenation might've been in the base class
        if(MethodInClass(buc, SrcSel))
        {
            Method SrcMe = class_getInstanceMethod(buc, SrcSel);
            if(SrcMe)
                method_setImplementation(SrcMe, NewImp);
        }
        else //Add an override in the current class
            class_addMethod(buc, SrcSel, NewImp, "v@:@@");
    }
}
```

And call it so:

```
Class buc = [bu class];
MountMethod(buc, @selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:), @selector(MyButton_SavedTouchesBegan:withEvent:));
    MountMethod(buc, @selector(touchesCancelled:withEvent:), @selector(MyButton_SavedTouchesCancelled:withEvent:));
    MountMethod(buc, @selector(touchesEnded:withEvent:), @selector(MyButton_SavedTouchesEnded:withEvent:));
    MountMethod(buc, @selector(touchesMoved:withEvent:), @selector(MyButton_SavedTouchesMoved:withEvent:));
```

This has the disadvantage of mounting the said methods for all buttons, not just for the ones desired. In the MyButton's implementation, there's an additional check if the drag-drop functionality is to be enabled for this particular button. For that I've used associated objects.

One fine point is that touchesXXX methods are implemented in the UIControl class, not in the UIButton. So my first, naive implementation of swizzling would replace the method in UIControl instead of the button class. The current implementation does not assume either way. Also, it makes no assumptions about the run-time class of buttons. Could be UIButton, could be anything (and in real iOS, it's UIRoundedRectButton).

Answer (score 0):

Check the states of the button in your NIB file. 
It's possible that you are looking at the "active" state or something rather than the more common UICONTROLSTATENORMAL.

Comment: No, the background and alpha are set for all states.